# SetTimeout on return of a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm conditionally passing style based on the state. I want to apply the transform AFTER the component is rendered because otherwise the transition won't happen. I'm being told the best way to achieve this is by setTimeout, but how can I timeout the return of a function?

```
style= {
    transition: 'transform 1s',
    ...this.zoomedIn && this.mobileZoom(i),
}

zoomedIn () {
  return ['zoomIn', 'addBg', 'zoom', 'removeBg'].includes(this.state.zoom)
}

mobileZoom () {
  const transform = this.state.transform.mobile
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    return {
      zIndex: 1070,
      transform: 'translateY(' + transform.offset + 'px) scale(' + transform.scale + ')'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A little confused, you mean you want to execute a function after a DOM element is rendered?

Comment: `how can I timeout the return of a function?` you cannot timeout the return. `setTimeout` is an end state and whatever is inside that will be processed _later_ - if you just put a `return` then you will have a function that executes _later_ produces some value and then sacrifices it to the gods of garbage collection as nothing else picks it up. What you could do is return a promise and act when the promise is fulfilled, for example, or have the code in the `setTimeout` contact something independant, so it doesn't rely on something else just "picking up" the value.

Comment: I don't know much about React, but I'd assume there is a component lifecycle, similar to Angular, with an equivalent to "onInit,", that would ensure the operation you're triggering will happen when expected. If it's a child component, there's probably a "onChildrenRender" or something. Alternatively you could dispatch an event from the rendered comp to the parent letting it know the child is ready, but again that's probably not necessary. 

I've found using timers for this kind of thing is a hazard. I would be surprised if React didn't have a robust component lifecycle for this.

Comment: Inside [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), React guarantees the DOM for the component exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not return value from the function if you set its return value to setTimeout function but you can do this:

```
zoomedIn () {
var send = new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       resolve(['zoomIn', 'addBg', 'zoom', 'removeBg'].includes(this.state.zoom));
     });
   });
   return send;
}

//call function like this

zoomedIn().then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); 
});
```